# Wireless Networking in Single-User Mode

Tags: network, command-line, airport, services, single-user

How to enable AirPort network (and other) services; in single-user mode?

---

**Input:**  *(including prompt string)*

```
bash-3.2# networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 <network> [password]
```

**Output:**

```
Error obtaining SC session.
All Wi-Fi network services are disabled.
```

---

So I tried to power up the interface.

---

**Input:**  *(including prompt string)*

```
bash-3.2# networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

**Output:**

```
Error obtaining SC session.
You cannot set Wi-Fi power because all AirPort network services are disabled.
```

---

Not letting me use Apple's native disk utility either. It seems like most basic system services are disabled by default.

---

**Input:**  *(including prompt string)*

```
bash-3.2# diskutil list
```

**Output:**

```
Unable to run because unable to use the DiskManagement framework.  
Common reasons include, but are not limited to, the DiskArbitration  
framework being unavailable due to being booted in single-user mode.
```

---

Comment: It would be good to know the exact model of Mac you're using and the version of macOS installed.